# AWS Lambda processing stream from DynamoDB

Tags: aws-lambda, streaming, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I'm trying to create a lambda function that is consuming a stream from dynamoDB table. However I was wondering which is the best practice to handle data that may not have been processed for some errors during the execution? For example my lambda failed and I lost part of the stream, which is the best way to reprocess the lost data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB Streams invokes the Lambda function for each event untill it successfully processes it (Untill the code calls success callback).

In an error situation while executing, you need to handle it in code unless otherwise  the Lambda won't continue with the remaining messages in the stream.

If there is a situation where you need to process the message separate due to an error, you can use the dead letter queue (with Amazon SQS) to push the message and continue with the remaining items in the stream. You can have a separate logic to process the messages in this queue.

Comment: Do DynamoDB Streams support Dead Letter Queues directly? If so, can you link to the documentation?

Comment: Yes, you can use the lambda DLQ as mentioned here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html#dlq
You also can control when the messages will arrive in the DLQ(MaximumEventAgeInSeconds) as explained here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-aws-lambda-controls-for-stream-processing-and-asynchronous-invocations/

Comment: You cannot directly use DLQ to get discarded synchronous records such as dynamoDB streams.  
To capture discarded records, you need to configure `destination on failure`:  
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-failure-handling-features-for-kinesis-and-dynamodb-event-sources/

Comment: I have a Lambda that attached to the DynamoDB stream. I configured retry attempts upto 5. I have SQS as on failure destination.  In some cases lambda is timing out and It retried upto 5 times. But lambda not discarding records from dynamoDB. It  still remains as its in Table

Answer (score 19):

This is handled for you. DynamoDB Streams, like Kinesis Streams, will resend records until they have been successfully processed. When you are using Lambda to process the stream, that means successfully exiting the function. If there is an error and the function exits unexpectedly, the DynamoDB stream will simply resend the record that was being processing.

The good thing is you are guaranteed at-least-once processing however, there are some things you need to look out for. Like Kinesis Streams, DynamoDB Streams are guaranteed to processes records in order. As a side effect of this, when a record fails to process, it is retried until it is successfully processed or it expires from the stream (possibly days) *before* processing any records behind it in the stream.

How you solve for this depends on the needs of your application. If you need at-least-once processing but don't need to guarantee that all records are processed in order, I would just drop the records into an SQS queue and do the processing off of the queue. SQS queues will also retry records that aren't successfully processed however, unlike DynamoDB and Kinesis Streams, records will not block each other in the queue. If you encounter an error when transferring a record from the DynamoDB Stream to the SQS Queue, you can just retry however, this may introduce duplicates in the SQS Queue.

If order is critical or duplicates can't be tolerated, you can use a SQS FIFO Queue. SQS FIFO Queues are similar to (Standard) SQS Queues except they they are guaranteed to deliver messages to the consumer in order and have a deduplication window (5 mins) where any duplicates added to the queue within that window will be discarded.

In both cases, when using SQS queues to process messages, you can setup a Dead Letter Queue where messages can automatically be sent if they fail to be processed N number of times.

TLDR: Use SQS Queues.

Answer (score 8):

Updating this thread as all the existing answers are stale.

AWS Lambda [now supports the DLQs for synchronous steam read from DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-failure-handling-features-for-kinesis-and-dynamodb-event-sources/) table stream.

With this feature in context, here is the flow that I would recommend:

1. [Configure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html) the event source mapping to include the DLQ arns and set the retry-attempts count. After these many retry, the batch metadata would then be moved to DLQs.
2. Set-up alarm on DLQ message visibility to get alert on impacted records.
3. DLQ message can be used to retrieve the impacted stream [record using KCL library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/developing-consumers-with-kcl.html)

ProTip: you can use attribute "Bisect on Function Error" to enable batch splitting. With this option, lambda would be able to narrow down on the impacted record.